# stacks -java with array implementation

Tags: arrays, stack

Write a program that keeps the following information on books:

```
Book title
Barcode
Author Name
Price
Edition
```

Books from ten different authors need to be piled in such a way that the user can access the information of one book at a time.

Note: Use an array implementation for the stack. Your program should validate the following:

- Addition of more than 10 books to your stack.
- Deletion of books when your stack is empty.

I created the class Book for keeping Book info(barcode,.....)
I create 10 objects of class book and save each in array.

then?*>

Comment: Create your stack implementation... You know what a stack is and what operation you can do on a stack, right?